# check condition in table definition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table as follows (Postgresql 9.3):

```
CREATE TABLE tab
(
  id integer NOT NULL;
  name citext NOT NULL,
  isdefault boolean default false
);
```

I want to add a `check` that will not accept more than one record with  `isdefault = True`. I know I can do it with `triggers` but I read about `Check Constraints` and was wondering if it can be done with it.

Comment: Add a UNIQUE constraint. (Have one TRUE value, rest of them as NULL.)

Comment: `CHECK` constraints can only assert something about a *single* row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a partial unique index:

```
create unique index on tab (isdefault)
where isdefault ;
```

That way you can also store `false` in that column. I personally prefer to set `boolean` columns to `not null` so that I never have to deal with `null` values in boolean expressions, but only `true` or `false`.

The `where` clause results in indexing *only* rows with `isdefault = true`. Rows with `isdefault = false` (or null) are not indexed. So the index never contains more than one row.

The indexed column isn't really important here. If you query the name column very often (for that single row) you might want to create the index on that column, so that the queries can get everything from the index.

Comment: Can you explain it further? I don't really understand how it works. suppose I have a row with isdefault =True and someone is trying to add another row with isdefault =True. What will happen?

Comment: @quack that index prevents adding a second row with `isdefault = true`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I understand that.. but I don't understand how it does it. If I read it correctly it shouldn't allow more than 1 false row either

Comment: @quack: no, because the index only contains rows with `isdefault = true` because of the `where` clause. The indexed column actually doesn't matter, if you query the name of that row very often you might want to use `on tab (name)` instead (but you have to keep the `where` clause - that's the "magic")

Answer (score 0):

Add a UNIQUE constraint. (Have one TRUE value, rest of them as NULL.)

```
CREATE TABLE tab
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name citext NOT NULL,
  isdefault boolean unique,
  check (isdefault is not false)
);
```

The check constraint is there just to make sure isdefault is either TRUE (one row), or NULL.